# How to set up collectfast for django on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, collectstatic

How can I set up [collectfast](https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast) for django on heroku?
This is assuming I've already successfully set up static files hosting and serving from Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To disable heroku's automatic collectstatic, run:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

2) Add the following to settings.py to use a table in your database for the `collectfast`'s caching. Commit and push the change to heroku.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    },
    'collectfast': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'collectfast_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 60,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000
        },
    },
}
COLLECTFAST_CACHE = 'collectfast'
```

4) To create the required cache table in the database, run:

```
heroku run createcachetable
```

5) To restore heroku's automatic collectstatic, run:

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
```

Each deploy will now correctly use collectfast to collect modified static files to s3.

Comment: You rock!  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @dmcmulle Glad it helped!